# execute python script with function from command line, Linux

Tags: python, linux, shell, command-line

I have my python file called convertImage.py and inside the file I have a script that converts an image to my liking, the entire converting script is set inside a function called convertFile(fileName)

Now my problem is I need to execute this python script from the linux command line while passing the convertFile(fileName) function along with it.

example:

```
 linux user$: python convertImage.py convertFile(fileName)
```

This should execute the python script passing the appropriate function.

example:

```
def convertFile(fileName):

    import os, sys
    import Image
    import string

    splitName = string.split(fileName, "_")
    endName = splitName[2]
    splitTwo = string.split(endName, ".")
    userFolder = splitTwo[0]

    imageFile = "/var/www/uploads/tmp/"+fileName

    ...rest of the script...

    return
```

What is the right way to execute this python script and properly pass the file name to the function from the liunx command line?

Thank in advanced

Comment: there's no such thing. Parse the `sys.argv` list and choose the right action. Check `argparse` the module

Comment: As mentioned by S.Lott, `<program> <subcommand> <command arguments>` is a very common style. It's best for the user to have command names, not knowledge of the internal implementation. And using parentheses (which require escaping in bash) as a required part of your syntax is just mean.

Comment: The parentheses were only for example reasons but I appreciated all the help and got it to work using sys.argv

Comment: @knittledan: `sys.argv` is -- usually -- a poor choice.  Notice that the answers all specifically recommended avoiding this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    command= " ".join( sys.argv[1:] )
    eval( command )
```

This will work.  But it's insanely dangerous.

You really need to think about what your command-line syntax is.  And you need to think about why you're breaking the long-established Linux standards for specifying arguments to a program.

For example, you should consider removing the useless `()`'s in your example.  Make it this, instead.

```
python convertImage.py convertFile fileName
```

Then, you can -- with little work -- use `argparse` to get the command ("convertFile") and the arguments ("fileName") and work within the standard Linux command line syntax.

```
function_map = { 
    'convertFile': convertFile,
    'conv': convertFile,
}
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument( 'command', nargs=1 )
parser.add_argument( 'fileName', nargs='+' )
args= parser.parse_args()
function = function_map[args.command]
function( args.fileName )
```

Comment: Good combination of briefly answering X by mostly addressing Y

Comment: @S.Lott What is the purpose of the function_map dict here? Why does it have two keys for the command?

Comment: If I have several functions, I need to have several function_maps?

Answer (score 6):

Quick and dirty way:

```
linux user$: python convertImage.py convertFile fileName
```

and then in convertImage.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    function = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], sys.argv[1])
    filename = sys.argv[2]
    function(filename)
```

A more sophisticated approach would use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) (for 2.7 or 3.2+) or [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html).

Answer (score 2):

Create a top-level executable part of your script that parses command-line argument(s) and then pass it to your function in a call, like so:

```
import os, sys
#import Image
import string


def convertFile(fileName):
    splitName = string.split(fileName, "_")
    endName = splitName[2]
    splitTwo = string.split(endName, ".")
    userFolder = splitTwo[0]

    imageFile = "/var/www/uploads/tmp/"+fileName

    print imageFile     # (rest of the script)

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    convertFile(filename)
```

Then, from a shell,

```
$ convertImage.py the_image_file.png
/var/www/uploads/tmp/the_image_file.png
```

Comment: does this require a hashbang?

Comment: This answer shows valid code but does not answer the question. OP asks how to call the function from cmd. Your example calls the argument from cmd.