# Can I test a function defined in a file manually in the terminal in vscode?

Tags: python, function, testing, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have previously only written python code using IDLE but since I am starting to do some more "heavier" programming I figured I should start using Visual Studio Code. I am however having issues doing things that I would like to do while coding to check that my functions are working as intended. The major thing I want to be able to do is if I have saved

```
def summa(x, y)   
  return x+y
```

in a file `sum.py`, then I would want to test run `summa(3, 4)` in the terminal.
In IDLE I am used to just running the file containing the function and then use it but I cannot figure out how to do that in Visual Studio Code.  However, I realize that it is possible to import the file into a REPL terminal but I would hope that there is some easier way of doing it.

Comment: I suggest you read the Python Test pages in the VSC docs, doing these test over and over by hand is not fun work

Answer (score 1):

You can start Python interactively and import your file as a module. Then your function will be available, so you can call it the way you want:

[image]

What I did was:

1. Open new terminal
2. Type: `$ python` to start an interactive session
3. Import module `import test` or the function from the module: `import summa from test`
4. Now I can call `summa()` and play with it in this manual manner

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to this question :

[execute python script with function from command line, Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691599/execute-python-script-with-function-from-command-line-linux)

You could also use the main function :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   summa(sys.argv)
```

So you just launch the script and it run the function